# Erratic spell checking

Tags: filetype-tex, spell-checking

I was editing the resume in latex I had downloaded from [here.](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/awesome-resume-cv)

Vim is most erratic when it comes to checking spelling. In the resume_cv.tex file, the spell checking works. When I open any of the linked files by opening them (using `Ctrl-W`+`gf` command), cv-sections/skills.tex, etc. spell checking does not work. The result is the same even if I open the files directly from the command line.

Completely unable to understand what is happening. How do I get spell checking back?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem is that the files in which spell checking isn't working are being detected as `filetype=plaintex`, but the file where it works is detected as `filetype=tex`.

If that's the case, then you can give Vim a hint that your `*.tex` files will always be LaTeX by adding `let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'` in your vimrc, as described in `:help ft-tex-plugin`.

Comment: Well, both the files were set as filetype=tex. But spellcheck works on one and not in the other. When I manually set ft=plaintex for both, spellcheck works.

I have added let g:tex_flavor = 'latex' in vimrc. Still I get the same behaviour. Still, both the files have ft=tex.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what exactly is happening under the hood. But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539203/3282596) is the remedy to the problem.

With that change in tex.vim, things work as expected.